# Mac automator: use variables in shell & growl notification

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator, growl

I am using an application automator file to recieve a file which gets set to the variable `file`, and then using Ask For Text to set a variable called `name`.

I need to use this in two places:

1. A shell script
2. In a growl notification

I've tried many combinations but I can't get the variables to work in either. What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your automator workflow:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    -- Get name from automator
    tell application "Finder" to set theName to name of file input

    -- pass name into shell script and get variable back
    set xxx to do shell script "echo " & theName

    display dialog xxx
end run
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to type any script. If you go to the Growl application, right click, show contents, Contents--->Library--> Automator

double click that file and a growl action will be added to Automator. 
Enjoy ;)

Comment: Thanks, but you can't use variables that way